# MySqlDataAdapter Fill input string format?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm getting an error when trying to fill a data table with data from a MySQL query using the adapter.

VisualStudio it's telling me the error, "**Input String was not in a correct format**," is on the line with `adapter.Fill(myDataTable);` (The procedure is just a basic select statement that returns some rows with text, varchar, and datetime values.)

the method is called like this: `GetDataTable("CALL SomeProc()");`

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(string query)
{
    string ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["randomconnstr"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnString);
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

    DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        adapter.Fill(myDataTable);
    }

    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return myDataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing a quotation mark, it doesn't look like you have closed the string.

```
GetDataTable(@"CALL SomeProc()");
```

EDIT **

Try Adding this :-

```
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: I thought the same but then I wondered how the application compiled to reach to this point `adapter.Fill(myDataTable);`

Comment: what is SomeProc() is that actually your query string?

Comment: SomeProc() would be a select statement that i have as a stored procedure.

Comment: @smarble is `SomeProc()` a function in your code? or just the name of your SP?

Comment: its just the name of a stored procedure.

Comment: still no luck with the edit ... it broke for a second because the in-string on that method just needs to be "SomeProc" now. but now its back to the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this

```
GetDataTable("CALL SomeProc()");
```

To This :

```
GetDataTable("SomeProc");
```

Comment: @smarble  Try This `GetDataTable("SomeProc;");`